# Build Class Library (Package) NuGet Package Projects Without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, asp.net-core

What do I need to do to build the new 'Class Library (Package)' (.xproj) projects (also used by ASP.NET 5) using MSBUILD without having Visual Studio installed? I currently get the error below:

> C:\Source\MyProject.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I am only targeting .NET 4.5.2, I have the Microsoft Build Tools 2015 already installed and want to do this on my build server.

**UPDATE**

It seems I can do a `dnu publish` to achieve this but that is only for a single .xproj project. What about if I want to publish several projects in a solution for my build environment? Adding projects individually is not very convenient.

Doing `MSBUILD MySolution.sln` would do this for standard class libraries. Is there a way to get `MSBUILD MySolution.sln` to work for this case?

Comment: When I set up a new build-server, there are usually a few "manually copy/deploy files" in the documentation I create.  Missing targets are the main ones.  I would just manually copy that file over and put it where it it looking for it.  Sql targets are also usually in this list.  But I agree, there should be a way to get these without installing VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need msbuild?

All you need is `dnvm` so you can acquire a `dnx`. After that you can run `dnu pack` and produce the packages.

Comment: I am executing `MSBuild MySolution.sln`. If I install DNVM, will this work or do I need to explicitly use `dnu pack`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using dnu build. (VS2015 also using this) All aspnet repro's can be build with the build.cmd without VS2015.

For an example see [asp live](https://github.com/aspnet/live.asp.net) or
[datatables](https://github.com/Anderman/Mvc.JQuery.Datatables)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dnu pack` to create a nuget package. Type `dnu pack --help` for more info

Comment: I am executing `MSBuild MySolution.sln`. If I install DNVM, will this work or do I need to explicitly use `dnu pack`?

Answer (score 0):

Check `dnvm list` to ensure the version you intend to build with matches what your projects target.  If it doesn't, use `dnvm use` to set it or `dnvm install` to install it.

Then `cd /your/solution/direcotry` and;

```
dnu restore
dnu build *
```